# Error Message: A nullable expression can't be used as a condition

Tags: flutter

How to fix this. Error message A nullable expression can't be used as a condition.
Try checking that the value isn't 'null' before using it as a condition.
[image]

This is my code.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () => _webcamVideoElement.srcObject.active ? _webcamVideoElement.play() : _webcamVideoElement.pause(),
      tooltip: 'Start stream, stop stream',
      child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
onPressed: () => _webcamVideoElement?.srcObject?.active ? _webcamVideoElement.play() : _webcamVideoElement.pause(),
```

Comment: Still not solve this error

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple, before each property that can be null you should check null, try to click "Quick Fix" with Ctrl+. (Mac Command+.) to see what  is suggested and that will probably fix it.

Also you didn't showed all your code, so I only can guess you are dealing with (VideoElement)[https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/VideoElement-class.html] in that case your `srcObject` can (be null)[https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-html/MediaElement/srcObject.html] in this case pretty close to what @Mohammad said, I suggest you to try this:

```dart
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: () => _webcamVideoElement.srcObject?.active ? _webcamVideoElement.play() : _webcamVideoElement.pause(),
      tooltip: 'Start stream, stop stream',
      child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Still not solve this error

Comment: Can you please provide you entire code? Would be easier for debug